# Little $o$ notation problem

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Determine the values ​​of $a$ and $b$ if

$$ \sqrt{x^2 +1}=ax + b +o(x) $$

when $x\to 0$ and prove the result,
where $o(x)$ corresponds to the notation little $o$.

My first attempt was to rewrite the equation as

$$ \sqrt{x^2 +1} -ax - b = o(x) $$

and use the definition of little $o$, then I would need to show that the next lim is equal to zero

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 +1} -ax - b }{x} = 0$$

in order to use L'Hopital I need $0/0$ in the direct evaluation. So if $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} -ax -b$ then I need $0= f(0) = 1-b $ or equivalent $b = 1$.

Using L'Hopital we need

$$  \frac{  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} }{\lim_{x \to 0}  1} = 0$$

Substituting x,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ -a }{1} = 0$$

So $a=0$. But I'm not sure I'm susing correctly the implications in L'Hopital Theorem cause I known the limit exists and I would like L'Hopital to be true but I feel I'm forcing the hyptesis. Is there anoher way t find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Alternatively, you only need to look for the tangent line approximation of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, which is simply the line $y=1$, so $\sqrt{x^2+1} = 1 + o(x)$

Comment: You started off correctly but after that got charmed by infamous L'Hospital's. Don't use the rule unless you are forced to. It's the last resort if all else fails. If the limit of a fraction is $f/g$ is $L$ and $g$ has limit $M$ then $f=(f/g) g$ tends to $LM$. With this your numerator tends to $0$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simpler, set $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ which is derivable in $0$.

Notice $f(0)=1$ therefore $\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\to f'(0)=0$

Which is nothing more than $\sqrt{1+x^2}=1+o(x)$